# map transformation i.text.toInt vs toInt(i.text)

Tags: scala

I was reading Beginning Scala and was trying out the examples in REPL. 
I created an xml and a toInt function as below

```
val x = <x>{(1 to 3).map(i => <i>{i}</i>)}</x>

def toInt(in : String) : Option[Int] = {
    try { 
      Some(Integer.parseInt(in)) 
    }
    catch {
      case e : Exception => None
    } 
  }
```

And I tried the following

```
(x \\ "i").map(i => i.text.toInt) // returns Seq[Int]

(x \\ "i").map(i => toInt(i.text)) // returns Sep[Option[Int]]
```

Why does the first version return Seq[Int] and the second version return Seq[Option[Int]] ?

Thanks

Comment: Because you've written so? The first is build-in method of String which fails with `java.lang.NumberFormatException` exception if it cannot convert String to Int. The second one (as you've written) tries to do the same, but it intercept exception and wraps result into Option container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is a build-in method, defined on [`StringLike`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringLike)

```
def toInt: Int = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(toString)
```

This one will throw an exception if it doesn't find an integer